# How to query with this Select statement in vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-ce

I am querying using this SQL statement in SQL Server 2008:

```
select 
    sum(tax + debit) + (select isnull(sum(tax + credit), 0)
                        from BILLTRANSACTION 
                        where (BillClass = 2 or BillClass = 5 or BillClass = 6)      
                          and (ClientID = 101383)  
                          and datediff(month, StatementOrRecptDate, '3-31-2018') >= 0 
                          and datediff(month, BeginDate, '3-31-2018') = 1)
from 
    BILLTRANSACTION 
where  
    (ClientID = 101383)  
    and datediff(month, EndDate, '3-31-2018') = 1
```

It works - now I am trying to apply it to my code in vb.net but it's not working.

By the way I have a local SQL Server Compact database, and I run my query against that, but it's not working.

This is the screenshot of my error: https://ibb.co/fKBkHy

Comment: It might help if you a) show your VB.NET code, as the error presumably is in there and b) specify "not working", e.g. post an error message or describe unexpected behaviour vs expected one.

Comment: Hi please post your code and the error code you received

Comment: SQL Server Compact Edition [supports only a subset of SQL Server T-SQL grammar](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173372.aspx). I suspect the subquery in the `SELECT` clause is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries are not generally allowed in aggregations.  So, just move the expression to the `from` clause:

```
select (sum(bt.tax + bt.debit) + coalesce(bt2.tax_credit, 0))
from billtransaction bt cross join
     (select sum(bt2.tax + bt2.credit) as tax_credit
      from billtransaction bt2 
      where bt2.BillClass in (2, 5, 6) and
            ClientID = 101383 and  
            datediff(month, StatementOrRecptDate, '2018-03-31') >= 0 and
            datediff(month, BeginDate, '2018-03-31') = 1
     ) bt2
where bt.ClientID = 101383 and
      datediff(month, bt.EndDate, '2018-03-31') = 1;
```

Notes:

- I added table aliases and qualified column names.  You should always use them when there is more than one table reference in the query.
- I fixed the date format to be ANSI/ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD format.
- I replaced `ISNULL()` with `COALESCE()`.  The latter is ANSI-standard.
- I replaced the sequence of `OR` expressions with `IN` -- easier to write, read, and maintain.

Comment: @Gordin it's not working I try to remove the (.) in bt2 before where clause but its says invalid column name 'tax_credit'